# Editing a non-visible, active layer

Tags: gimp, layers

I just started using Gimp 2.10, and I love it except for one small thing that is absolutely killing me right now.

When I set the active layer as not visible and then try editing it (I do a lot of pixel art, and I'd take a layer, set it to non visible, and erase a couple pixels so the layer under it would have a few parts that would look like its above the layer that is invisible), but I get a warning at the bottom saying "The active layer is not visible" and it doesn't erase the pixels I'm trying to erase.

I don't want to mess with the layer transparency, or have to make another layer above the other one, so how would I turn off the warning and edit the layer when it isn't set as visible?

Comment: GIMP 2.8.x allowed editing pixels on a hidden layer. Perhaps it's a new feature? In any case, you could just unhide the layer, then when you've finished hide it again.

Answer (score 0):

This is a deliberate change from the behavior of 2.8 in GIMP 2.10, and has actually been in the code of the GIMP master branch for quite some time (about 5 years).

The [code change](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/commit/ac5428787e238282fdbf1359ebfd4445cb0fcec8) was done to implement a feature request: [Bug 598523 - Protect hidden layers from editing](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=598523)

You can suggest improvements, for example to make this a configurable option. 
If you want to do so, then you should file an issue at https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/issues